# Url not displaying in whatsapp android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I am using an image and text to share in whatsapp and other email and sms through intent.

But problem in whatsapp is, image is displaying, text too displaying but url is not displaying as link. It's displaying as normal text. You can see the below code as follows.

```
 Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(photoFile.getAbsolutePath()); //getting image 
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                //Target whatsapp:
                shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                //Add text and then Image URI
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Sharing the details.\n\n" +
                        "QR Code:" + QRCode + "\n" +
                        "Nama Retailer:" + retailerName + "\n" +
                        "Nama Owner:" + ownerName + "\n" +
                        "Nomer TRX:" + normorTrx + "\n" +
                        "Disclaimer" + "\n" +
                        "Please use the below link" + " "+
                                "http://116.12.2/images/disclaimer/NG20_SaTria_TC_Legal_050418_DISCLAIMER.pdf" +" "+
                                "for further information."
                        );

                shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
                shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

                try {
                    if (shareIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivity(shareIntent);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(RetailerQRCodeGenerationActivity.this, "not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(RetailerQRCodeGenerationActivity.this, "Application not available.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Comment: May i know why it has been downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to share a url you generally do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sharing URL");
i=intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.url.com");
```

But you want to share two different type of intents, because I am seeing in your code that you are using `shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");`

Two share different types of elements you need to use multiple MIME types like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("*/*");
String[] mimeTypes = {"image/*", "text/*"};
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
```

For more details check: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics#MIMETypeReference

Comment: Thanks. Let me check it.